# What all are the reasons for a bluetooth device to be undiscoverable

Tags: bluetooth

One reason is obvious that the user has not made the device discoverable. I am looking for others.

I have observed (I guess everyone has), that while scanning for bluetooth devices, we do not get a list of "all" discoverable devices "everytime". It is random as per the developer docs I usually read, but I want a reason behind this randomness - and I feel the reasons are there on both the "scanner" device as well as "scanned" device.

For instance, on my Android phone, if I press the "Scan" button immediately after one scan is over, I get hardly 30% of the devices I got in the first scan. This makes me wonder what goes wrong ! (Please note that I am talking about the freshly "discovered" devices in the second scan - the list which is shown by most devices displays old "cached" devices discovered in the previous scans)

A (related) question is that if I somehow increment the scan time (on my Android device) from 12 seconds to 30 seconds, do I have a better chance of discovering missing devices ?

PS : Though I haven't tagged this question with Android, but I will be happy to get Android specific answers too, alongwith any low-level answers ) in terms of bluetooth terminology)

Comment: Can I please get reasons behind negative votes ? Will serve as a future guideline... thanks !

Comment: Raj, this is a computer technology question, it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @BenVoigt In principle I agree, however, a certain part of bluetooth programming problems stem from not understanding the inherent limitations of bluetooth. This post asks about one such aspect, and I think that it would be useful as a background for bluetooth programmers even if there is no concrete code involved.

Comment: Seems like I missed the philosophy behind SO ! I am moving to another forum then. I don't know how to voluntarily close this question... if you can help, I will.

Comment: @jhonkola: A certain part of understanding electricity helps with programming battery management code also, but that doesn't make all http://electronics.stackexchange.com question on-topic here!

Comment: @BenVoigt However, characteristics of radio based networks (WiFi, BT, 3G, ...) have much more direct influence on the networking code written to use them than electricity fundamentals do on battery management code (unless maybe talking about code deep inside the OS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bluetooth discovery works by broadcasting inquiry packets across the available radio spectrum. Any bluetooth device in discoverable mode will send an answer for the packets it receives. Due to the details of the radio layer of bluetooth, it is not guaranteed that all devices within range will receive an inquiry packet, however, in practice the probability is close to 100% if the scan is run for the typical 10 seconds.

Much more probable reason for the variance is due to the short range of bluetooth, typically 10 to 20 meters. Thus, it is entirely possible that devices that were within range during the first scan have moved so that they are no longer in range. This is the probably the reason if you are doing the scan in a place with a lot of people moving around.

Another reason related to the short range is that some devices may be at the edge of the bluetooth range so that there is a large probability that either the inquiry packet or inquiry response packet gets lost in transmission. While bluetooth chipsets will provide a RSSI value for the inquiry responses that could be used to roughly estimate the range (in BT 2.1 ->, IIRC), this information is not typically shown by the inquiry functions (e.g. Android inquiry does not show this).

Comment: Thanks jhonkola ! But the issue I am having is for Class 1 devices (with range about 100 m) ; and all are statically placed besides each other. Still the devices are randomly discovered.

Comment: This could possibly also then be radio interference, if there are many class 1 devices transmitting at the same time close to each other. You could try with two devices and see if there is variance with the results. Or you could move the devices further apart from each other and see if this helps with the randomness.

Comment: Yes, when I tried with 4 devices, it showed higher probability of missing a device compared to a scan with only 2 devices. But this still doesn't explain my earlier scenario when I scan consecutively (without delay) and miss a big number of devices in the second scan..can that again be interference ?

Comment: Maybe, it is difficult to say. What I know is that the inquiry protocol practically fills up the available radio spectrum with the inquiry and inquiry response packets (they are sent on every channel). This is usually not a problem as the transmission is so short ranged, but with class 1 devices the range is greater.